# how to initialize all Select2 dropdowns on a page with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 from http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Right now I am initializing the dropdowns like this:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() { 

 $('.form_control').select2({
     minimumResultsForSearch: -1
 });

  });
 </script>
```

The problem is, I have a page where I am dynamically generating the dropdowns based orders, so I will have multiple dropdowns and forms with the same class on the same page, like this:

```
<select id="order_status" class="form-control" name="order_status">

<option value="">Option 1</option>
<option value="">Option 2</option>

</select>
```

When I do this, the first dropdown initializes fine, but all the others on the same page don't. How do I get it to initialize ALL of the form_control dropdowns?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hryoy8rc/1/

Comment: By the way, I could assign unique IDs to the dropdowns, but they could be anywhere from 000001 to 683935 so that's not a good option either.

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hryoy8rc/1/

Answer (score 4):

its a bug in current version, i faced same issue  use 4.0.0 and it will fix your issue: 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad I wasn't actually losing my mind. It seems to have broke starting 4.0.6, so 4.0.5 worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try my code below...

```js
$('.form_control').each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).select2({
        minimumResultsForSearch: -1
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="order_status" class="form-control" name="order_status">

<option value="">Option 1</option>
<option value="">Option 2</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up giving each dropdown a dynamically generated ID like drop_003 and then initializing it inside the body like this:

```
<script>
$('#drop_003').select2({
minimumResultsForSearch: -1
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Select2 4.0.2 version and this snippet is working for me. It will initialize all select elements in a page into Select2.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('select').select2();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically generating the boxes, I had to actually loop the options instead of using the helper.

Solution here:

```js
$('.myselect').select2();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" role="form">
    <p> working boxes </p>   

    <select class="form-control myselect">
      <option>Service 1</option>
      <option>Service 2</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select class="form-control myselect">
      <option>Service 1</option>
      <option>Service 2</option>
    </select>
    
</form>
```